# SQL Server Sum greater than date shown

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have a table that is called employees:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees
(
   Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
   FullName NOT NULL NVARCHAR(100)
)
```

I have another table called Sales

```
CREATE TABLE SALES 
(
   Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
   CustomerId INT NOT NULL FOREGIN KEY REFERENCES SOMETABLE(id),
   AMOUNT DECIMAL(15,4) NOT NULL,
   EmployeeId INT NOT NULL FOREGIN KEY REFERENCES Employees(Id),
   SaleDate DATETIME2 NOT NULL
)
```

And another table called Calls

```
CREATE TABLE Calls
(
   Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
   Date DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
   EmployeeId INT NOT NULL FOREGIN KEY REFERENCES Employees(Id)
)
```

I need to run a query that will tell me the last date an employee sold something and how may calls they've mad since that sale.

What I have tried is

```
SELECT
      LAST_DATE_SOLD = MAX(Sales.Date)
    , Employees.FullName
    , Count(Calls.*)
FROM Employees
LEFT OUTER JOIN SALES ON Sales.EmployeeId = Employees.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Calls On Calls.EmployeeId = Employees.Id
GROUP BY Employees.FullName
```

I am not getting the correct values if someone could help with this that would be great.

Comment: What values are you getting? How are you determining they are incorrect? Please give us a some known failing sample data.

Comment: I am getting 1 on all employees, i know they are correct because I have entered the data myself. it should be around 10 per employee

Comment: the last date entered is correct. just the count isnt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to skin this cat. Here is one of them. Notice that this is joining to Calls where the date is greater than the last sale date so it only returns those calls.

```
with SortedResults as
(
    select *
        , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by e.EmployeeID order by s.SalesDate desc) as RowNum
    from Sales s
    join Employee e on e.EmployeedID = s.Id
)

select s.SalesDate
    , s.FullName
    , count(*)
from SortedResults s
join Calls c on c.EmployeedId = s.EmployeeId and c.Date > s.SaleDate
where s.RowNum = 1
group by s.SalesDate, s.FullName
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `Max(Sales.Date)` is not correct. Try this

```
SELECT
      LAST_DATE_SOLD = MAX(SaleDate)
    , Employees.FullName
    , Count(Calls.*)
FROM Employees
LEFT OUTER JOIN SALES ON Sales.EmployeeId = Employees.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Calls On Calls.EmployeeId = Employees.Id
GROUP BY Employees.FullName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
WITH    qry1
      AS ( SELECT   EmployeeId ,
                    MAX(SaleDate) LatestSaleDate
           FROM     dbo.SALES
           GROUP BY EmployeeId
         )
SELECT  qry1.EmployeeId ,
        LatestSaleDate ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.date > LatestSaleDate THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
            END) NumberOfCalls
FROM    qry1
        LEFT JOIN Calls c ON qry1.EmployeeId = c.EmployeeId
GROUP BY qry1.EmployeeId, LatestSaleDate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.fullname,
       c.date,
       COUNT(c.id)
  FROM calls c
 INNER JOIN employees e
    ON c.employee_id = e.employee_id
 WHERE date >= (SELECT MAX(saledate)
                  FROM sales
                 WHERE employee_id = c.employee_id
                )
 GROUP BY e.fullname,
          c.date
```